# Azure DevOps API: powershell get list of test points

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to get list of test points data via Azure DevOps API?

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9KbI.png)

I tried this powershell script

```
function GetUrl() {
    param(
        [string]$orgUrl, 
        [hashtable]$header, 
        [string]$AreaId
    )

    # Area ids
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/work-with-urls?view=azure-devops&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#resource-area-ids-reference
    # Build the URL for calling the org-level Resource Areas REST API for the RM APIs
    $orgResourceAreasUrl = [string]::Format("{0}/_apis/resourceAreas/{1}?api-preview=5.0-preview.1", $orgUrl, $AreaId)

    # Do a GET on this URL (this returns an object with a "locationUrl" field)
    $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $orgResourceAreasUrl -Headers $header

    # The "locationUrl" field reflects the correct base URL for RM REST API calls
    if ("null" -eq $results) {
        $areaUrl = $orgUrl
    }
    else {
        $areaUrl = $results.locationUrl
    }

    return $areaUrl
}

$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/fodservices"
$personalToken = "<my token pat>"

Write-Host "Initialize authentication context" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

Write-Host "Demo 3"

$coreAreaId = "3b95fb80-fdda-4218-b60e-1052d070ae6b"
$tfsBaseUrl = GetUrl -orgUrl $orgUrl -header $header -AreaId $coreAreaId

$relDefUrl = "$($tfsBaseUrl)/_apis/testplan/Plans/70152/Suites/70154/TestPoint?api-version=5.0-preview.2"
try {
    $output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $relDefUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

}
catch{
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription

}
$output.value | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.id
}
```

the result is:

Demo 3

StatusCode: 404

StatusDescription: Not Found

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong im new to using powershell and azure devops rest api

Comment: What is the value of `$tfsBaseUrl`? It needs to include the team project.

Comment: I edited and added the function 'geturl' i used at first and the token i have + the url im using

Comment: Right, but look at the contents of that variable. It includes the organization name, but **not** the project name. You need to include the project name in the URL. Look at the documentation and compare your URL to the documentation's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the contents of the `$tfsBaseUrl` variable. It includes the organization name, but not the project name. You need to include the project name in the URL. Look at the documentation and compare your URL to the documentation's URL.

Comment: I tried : $relDefUrl = "$($tfsBaseUrl)/Training%20projects/_apis/testplan/Plans/70152/Suites/70154/TestPoint?api-version=5.0-preview.2"

but same problem

Comment: Still a bit stuck in this, if there is a solution i'll welcome any help and thnx in advance